# length on regex when vertical bar exist

Tags: regex

I am new to regex. I want to check the length on regex.

Regex: `(%23)?([0-9]|[A-Z]|%2F|-)`

I want to restrict length to 1-30.

> %231234567890 should be invalid.
>   %231234567 should be valid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your invalid example has 13 characters long.. I'm just confused

Comment: Your regex is rather over-complicated, compared to the examples you have given. It would be helpful for you to provide a more thorough set of matching/non-matching examples.

Comment: Also, please edit your question with the tag of your language/tool

Comment: A possible solution would be to add `^` at the start and the quantifier you wish `{6}` at the end, look this [example.](https://regex101.com/r/hG4yJ4/1)

Comment: The `%2F` part makes no sense. Is that supposed to be the hex value of a character (`/`)? If not, and it's a literal string, can it be repeated? And to verify the length of the string, the flavor of the regex would help (JS, .NET, php, ...).

Comment: sorry , restrict length 1-10 instead of 1-30..

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest with a lookahead `(?=^.{1,10}$)…`, in your case:

```
(?=^.{1,10}$)(%23)?([0-9]|[A-Z]|%2F|-)+
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3dn9k)